# Refer to proper line in TOC in LaTeX

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I am trying to optimize my PDF (big songbook, ~400 pages) made in LaTex to enable better navigating in it. Almost every subsection takes only 1 or 2 pages, so the TOC is very long, about 10 pages.
I am using `hyperref` package.

I have clickable TOC and then every headings is made as `\hyperlink` which refer back to TOC.

Is posible to force my headings refer not to first page of TOC, but to page, on which the properly line (for this heading) is?

I tried some redefinitions of `\mysubsection`:

- use `\subsection*` and then `\addcontentsline` instead of `\subsection`
- in `\addcontentsline` made some `\label` or `\hypertarget` on which i can refer

but nothing worked for me... Any suggestion?

```
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\mysubsection}[1]{
    \subsection*{\hyperlink{toc:\the\numexpr\value{subsection}}{#1}}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\label{toc:\the\numexpr\value{subsection}} #1}
    \setcounter{subsection}{\the\numexpr\value{subsection} + 1}
    }
```